# .htaccess don't go to folder if slash on end

Tags: .htaccess

I have site where

`site.com/index.php?page=test`  (include file `test.php` from `pages` folder into index.php)

is replaced by `site.com/test`

### Goal:

If I go to `site.com/index.php?page=forum/new_enrty`

I want ot make url `site.com/forum/new-entry`

### Problem:

if I open `site.com/forum/new-entry` it directs me to forum directory to new-entry file directly and not include new-entry into index.php

### So far I got this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteBase /cms/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```